# Fetching rows from 1 table and inserting it into another

Tags: php

I have to fetch all the rows from table workplan_progress and insert it to another table exco. I have used this code but got no result. No data can be seen in the exco table. I tried a lot of other methods too but kept getting no answer at all.

```
include("includes/connect.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM workplan_progress where id='$id'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$value1 = $row['division_name'];
$value2 = $row['division_chief'];
$value3 = $row['period'];
$value4 = $row['month'];
$value5 = $row['activity_name'];
$value6 = $row['unit'];
$value7 = $row['weightage'];
$value8 = $row['per_100'];
$value9 = $row['per_75'];
$value10 = $row['per_50'];
$value11 = $row['per_<50'];
$value12 = $row['measurement'];
$value13 = $row['score'];
$value14 = $row['progress'];
$value15 = $row['indicator_measure'];

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO 'exco' SET                 division_name='$value1',
                                                division_chief='$value2',
                                                period='$value3',
                                                month='$value4',
                                                activity_name='$value5',
                                                unit='$value6',
                                                weightage='$value7',
                                                per_100='$value8',
                                                per_75='$value9',
                                                per_50='$value10',
                                                perless50='$value11'
                                                measurement='$value12'
                                                score='$value13'
                                                progress='$value14'
                                                indicator_measure='$value15'
                                                ";

$query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
if(isset($query1)){
        $_SESSION['msg']='This work progress has been forwarded to exco for approval.';
    }
    echo "<script>window.location='admin_workprogress.php?msg=success'</script>";
```

?>

Comment: check for errors :http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: `INSERT INTO exco (division_name, ...) SELECT divison_name, ... FROM workplan_progress WHERE id='$id';` - You can do this in one simple query.

Comment: What do you get if right after this line: `$row=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);` you add this: `var_dump($row);`

Comment: @larsAnders bool(false) message and success message is displayed and the fetched rows becomes empty. But the values are not inserted in the exco table in the database.

Comment: @Bishal_bh You probably need to remove the window.location redirect to debug this file. Are you accessing this page with a URL like `thispage.php?id=6`? Because this line `$id=$_GET['id'];` is looking for an id in the URL. If you just go to `thispage.php` then both `$_GET['id']` and `$id` will be empty.

Comment: @larsAnders So what do u suggest me to do??

Comment: `1` Comment out the `echo "<script..."` redirect line just for testing. `2` Go to the page with a url like `thispage.php?id=6`. Use an id number you know already exists in the database. `3` See if the var_dump from $row has any content at all. We need to determine if the first SELECT statement works. I'm not sure exactly what you meant by "bool(false) message and success message is displayed".

Comment: actually i have another page for fetching the data and it works fine. At the end of that page i have included a link like this <a href='exco.php?id=$row[id]'>Forward to Exco</a>. The above mentioned page is exco.php i think im getting these errors due to redirecting. Is there a simple way of extracting rows from a table and after hitting submit the same information is inserted to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have single quotes around the name of the table here:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO 'exco' SET
```

What you need is either this without single quotes:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO exco SET
```

or better, this with backticks:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `exco` SET
```